# GWT - Ensure SQL password is never handed to the client

Tags: security, gwt

I have a GWT project where the server needs to talk to an SQL database. It needs a password to do that. That password needs to be stored somewhere. I can think of three locations to store that password:

1. Right there in the call to `DriverManager.getConnection`.
2. A `final String` field somewhere.
3. A .properties file.

With cases 1 and 2, the scenario comes to mind that the source code is translated to JavaScript and sent to the client.
That would never happen intentionally since it only makes sense for the server to talk to the database and not the client, but it could happen accidentally. In case 1 GWT would probably complain that it can't deal with JDBC, but in case 2 the field might be in some `Constants` class that compiles just fine.
I don't have enough experience with GWT to know how .properties files are handled. E.g. files in the `src\foo\server` directory might not be included in the JavaScript that gets handed to the client, but someone might come along later and accidentally move the file somewhere else where it is included.

So how can I ensure that the password is never accidentally sent to the client?

Note that I **don't care** that the password is stored in plain-text, either in code or in a config file.

**Edit:**

Clarification of my current situation:
My `TestModule.gwt.xml` **only** contains `<source path='client'/>`. It does **not** contain `<source path='shared'/>` or `<source path='server'/>`!
[image]
I have shared configs and server-only configs (the server-only config would contain the password for the database, then):
[image]
In the TestScreen (which is a Composite that shows a button on the page) I can use the ServerConfig class and SharedConfig class from client code without any problems:
[image]

[image]

[image]

This is a problem since I (or someone else) might accidentally cause the class with the password to be translated to JS and sent to the client.

Comment: The `client` part is translated to JavaScript, `server` is not, and so it is not sent to the browser. The `shared` part is used as both `client` and `server`. So, anywhere in the `server` part should be OK in your case.

Comment: @Adam Please give citations to your claims. I can use classes located in the "server part" (i.e. "src\some\package\server\MyClass.java") in client code (i.e. "src\some\package\client\LoginScreen.java") without any problem as long as the server-class doesn't use anything server-specific. I can't run it right now, but the test string is definitely contained in the output JS.

Comment: @NikoO please double check how did you configure your GWT project. Adam is right.

Comment: @NikoO see [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideModuleXml) for `<source path="_path_" />` element in module gwt.xml file, [here](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideOrganizingProjects.html#DevGuideModules) for Source Path explanation and both [Client-side code](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideCodingBasics.html#DevGuideClientSide) and [Server-side Code](http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideServerCommunication.html#DevGuideServerSide).

Comment: @Rade_303 I checked and I can't see anything that would indicate that the server-side code is to be translated.

Comment: @Adam I haven't yet read through the entire documentation but waht I've read so far is basically what one would expect. Add a <source.../> element to translate code in that folder. Don't add the element and it won't be translated. But clearly in my project the code is translated anyways. See the edit for a demonstration. So either the documentation is wrong or it's a bug or something in my project is wonky. I need to know what it is.

Answer (score 4):

The database password should rather be stored in a properties file than somewhere in the code. Unlike the code, this properties file should not be submitted to a version control system (like git or similar). It should also be outside the web folders.

Moreover, it would be huge security risk to use public final static String to store a password. Public members are visible to all other classes, static means no instance necessary to use it and final that it won't change. In your code you are storing a String constant that will be available to all instances of the class, and to other objects using the class. That is no good way to start considering security risks and is not directly related to GWT. It would be like storing a lot of money in a bank with no walls or doors and then asking how one could make it safe.

As long as data stays in the server side, you're fine. Per default, only client and shared paths are specified for translatable code. If your server classes do not implement IsSerializable and are not explicitly specified for translatable code in your gwt.xml file, they won't be sent to the client.

Comment: Makes sense to store it in a properties file to not check it into source control. But I need to know that I cannot accidentally reference that file from client code and then have it included in the generated JS, like it happens with code. Please see the Edit in the original post for a demonstration.

Answer (score 2):

You have more than one option here :

- Use a sperate classpath for both client a server so the classes in the server are never referenced in the client, this can be done following the recommended prject structure where each of the client/shared/server are a separate project, you can create such project structure using https://github.com/tbroyer/gwt-maven-archetypes, when you use this most likely the build will fail when anyone tries to depends on the server from the client, but there is still the possibilty that someone will do something and make it work.
- Use `@GwtIncompatible` annotation on the class that holds the password which means the class will never be transpiled to JS at all and if referenced from the client side it will be a compilation error at gwt compilation phase.
- Never put the password in a source file and depend on environment variable or some sort of password/key store that only exists on the server where you deploy the app and you still can set it locally for development.

Comment: * Please see my comment under Colin Alworth's answer. Do you **know** that the same kind of inlining won't happen and that the build will fail? Have you tested this?  
* I tried adding @GwtIncompatible to the ServerConfig class and it did not have any effect. The project compiles fine and the code runs and displays both alerts with the expected strings.  
* That would be preferable, but it makes the system more complicated. It's a long-term goal.

Comment: Yes I can confirm that should work, I added a class with a constant String, then annotated the class with `com.google.gwt.core.shared.GwtIncompatible` then referenced the constant in an Alert in the client side and the GWT compilation failed.. so maybe make sure you are using the right annotation. e.g `GwtIncompatible` vs `GwtCompatible` that might come from other third party libs.

Comment: Colin is right, that kind of inlining can happen, and thats is exactly why you should never have passwords stored in the source code and why you should externalize this as part of the deployment environment.

Answer (score 2):

If the server types and members are still accessible, you have misconfigured the .gwt.xml file, as @Adam said - make sure that the server vs client vs shared packages all exist in together in the same package as your .gwt.xml, and that no other .gwt.xml might exist.

This is not a security feature, like you are treating it, but a "how do I get the code I actually need to do my work" issue - java bytecode doesn't have enough detail in it (generics are erased, and old versions of gwt actually used javadoc tags for more detail) to generate the sources. Generally speaking, if you don't have sources, you can't pass that Java to GWT and expect it to be used in producing JS.

There are at least two edge case exceptions to this. There are probably more, but these spots of weirdness usually only matter when trying to understand why GWT *can't* generate JS from some Java, whereas you are trying to leverage these limitations as security features.

- Generators and linkers run in the JVM, so naturally they can function with just plain JVM bytecode while the compiler is running. It would be a weird case where you would care about this, but consider something like a generator which was trying to extract some kind of reflection information and provide it in a static format for the browser.
- GWT uses JDT to read the classes to be compiled, and it loads up bytecode where possible to resolve some things - one of those things happens to include constants. A "static final" string or primitive can be read from bytecode in this way *without* needing to go to the original `.java` sources.

If you have content in your bytecode that must not be considered in any way when generating JS, it belongs in a separate classpath - generally speaking, you should always separate your client code from your server code into separate projects with separate classpaths. There may exist at least one more project, to signify "shared" code which both client and server need to have access to.

And finally, it is *generally* speaking considered a bad idea to put secrets of any kind in your project itself, whether in the code itself or properties files, but instead to make it part of the deployment or runtime environment.

Comment: There is only one .gwt.xml file and right next to it are the three folders. See screenshots. I changed the `public static final String Password = ...;` to `public static String getPassword() { return ...; }` and would you look at that, now the GWT compiler errors out. I guess there's some kind of constant inlining going on before GWT sees its input.

Comment: The build process is already finicky and time-consuming enough; I don't want to create **another** two projects that I need to compile separately and then duct-tape the output files together. And I assume the inlining would happen anyways. Pulling the database-details out of the code is a long-term goal, but right now I just want a big red flag showing up if I make a mistake.

Comment: You have somewhat conflicting goals: you want to be sure it is impossible to reference class A from package B, but cannot take steps to ensure that this cannot happen. I think you need to decide which is more important. Perhaps consider some kind of static analysis as a close third option? This won't protect against an overly-helpful generator though - if you want isolated classpaths, you have to actually isolate them.